# SEO friendly URL issue

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

I have a problem in after creating SEO friendly links in my site.
here is the .htaccess file codes.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^www/category/([0-9]+)/(.*?).html$ www/product/productlist.php?category=$1 [L]
```

preciously i have this link

```
http ://www.mysite.com/www/product/productlist.php?category=00136
```

now SEO link is this

```
http ://www.mysite.com/www/category/00136/aprons.html
```

this is working okay.

and the issue im having is after the page loads all other site links also changed.
and those links are having these extra lines(www/category/) in the url now
how to avoid this thing.

site normal links like

```
http ://www.mysite.com/www/content/index.php
```

now link shows

```
http ://www.mysite.com/www/category/content/index.php
```

how to avoid adding these folder names - www/category/

other links are having short url like this-

```
a href='../../www/content/index.php'
```

Thanks

im realy appreciate valuable response for this

Answer (score 1):

Your links should start with a slash to indicate the link is relative to the website root.

```
/content/index.php
```