# how to rewrite or shorten the Sitecore URL

Tags: url-rewriting, sitecore, sitecore7

I have **Sitecore** website with URL 
http://www.abc.com/our-resorts/resort1/career.aspx
But I want to shorten the URL like 
http://www.abc.com/resort1/career.aspx . Any idea how to remove `our-resorts` from the URL.

[image]

Please any one from Sitecore community help me ....

thanks

Comment: is it necessary to have the add resorts in the site tree. if you really need to shorten this but need our-resorts, try a [tiny url.](http://tinyurl.com/)

Comment: abc is my starting point and i have many resorts under our-resorts item, so for seo purpose and mainly requirement is to produce url without our-resorts

Comment: you may need redirects. maybe this [post helps.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170026/pretty-url-seo-friendly-url). To keep it seo friendly, see this [guide.](http://flippa.com/blog/guide-to-redirects-for-seo/)

Comment: one more guide on rewrite rules for your sites can be found [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162396/seo-friendly-url-issue?rq=1)

Comment: @AndrewScottEvans , i cant use both guide in my case. because i have number of pages under our-resorts , so by this approach i have to write each and every redirect manually . But i want something generic ....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first answer that comes to my mind is to use custom `LinkProvider` (to generate the urls on the site) and custom `ItemResolver` (to resolve items when shortened url comes).

1. Create your own class `MyLinkProvider` inheriting from `Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider` and override `GetItemUrl` method. If the url contains `/our-resorts/`, remove `our-resorts`. Of course this assumes that you don't have out items with the name `our-resorts` which should not be omitted in link generation. Replace in Sitecore.config standard `LinkProvider` with the new one.
2. Create `MyItemResolver` class inheriting from `HttpRequestProcessor` and add it to the `<httpRequestBegin>` pipeline directly after `ItemResolver`. Code for the new item resolver:

```cs
public class ItemResolver : HttpRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        if (Context.Item != null || Context.Database == null || args.Url.ItemPath.Length == 0)
            return;
        string path = "/our-resorts" + MainUtil.DecodeName(args.Url.ItemPath);
        Context.Item =  args.GetItem(path);
    }
}
```

I haven't compiled or tested the code so you need to test it on your own. If you have any more questions, post them below.

Comment: As a supplement to the answer above, here's a useful blog post from John West which talks about creating a Custom Link Provider http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/02/Override-the-Link-Provider-to-Allow-Media-and-Exclude-Items-with-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx

Comment: Another awesome supplement to that is a blog post from Alistair Deneys about removing item bucket paths from the URL.  http://adeneys.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/item-buckets-and-urls/

Comment: @Maras , thanks for the help and i used this in my solution and it is working. But i can only use this when i have to remove our-resorts from the URL, because we hard coded the value in Item resolver, if i have another scenario where i have to remove any word from the URL to get an ideal URL . what should i use in that case.

Comment: An option would be to add a checkbox on the base page template "hide in url" that would be checked while generating url from `LinkManager`. Similar in `ItemResolver` you could check if any of the items with hidden urls contains a child matching to the request. You should remember that if you have too many items, your solution will be slower unless you use some proper caching of e.g. lucene for retrieving items based on the request.

Comment: Maras ,, is it possible to use title name as URL of the item , instead of using item-name. Title is field in my template so i want that my URL will be what ever i write in this Title field.

Comment: It's not possible out of the box. The default linkprovider has an option called "useDisplayName". But it will still build the url based on the page hierarchy.

Comment: Sam, if you want source code that you can use as a basis, check out our module: http://www.partechit.nl/nl/blog/2013/05/sitecore-seo-friendly-url-module It will be fairly easy to modify it with things like using a 'Title' field instead of item name and still have it resolve URL's properly.

Answer (score 2):

If it's not too many pages, you can just use URL Aliases in Sitecore.
They have to be setup manually for each item.

That way you can tell Sitecore that, for example, `/our-resorts/resort1/career` is accessible through the URL `/resort1/career`

[image]